# Can not install modules

Tags: 9

I am on a fresh Drupal 9.1.7 setup (tried PHP 7.4 and PHP 8.0).
When trying to install modules I get the following error:

```
Uncaught PHP Exception Drupal\Core\File\Exception\NotRegularDirectoryException: "temporary://update-extraction-03ad2725/$MODULENAME is not a directory." at /data/web/xxx/html/yyy/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/File/FileSystem.php line 662
```

But when I check, the directory actually is in place:

```
drwxrwxrwx  2 xxx www-data 4.0K Apr 25 10:43 update-extraction-03ad2725
```

What do I need to do in order to be able to install modules via Web interface?

Installation via composer is working.

Comment: If it works from CLI it’s likely to be a file permission issue. It’s not typically a good idea for your web server to be able to write to the modules folder anyway, so it would be best to continue using composer and ignore the UI method

Comment: The error message is about *update-extraction-03ad2725/$MODULENAME*, not *update-extraction-03ad2725*. It says that *update-extraction-03ad2725/$MODULENAME* isn't a directory.